# Eclipse interpreter / workspace relative paths on USB drive

Tags: windows, eclipse, usb-drive

I have Eclipse and python installed on a USB drive, and I use it for my programming classes. I know that I could just have the workspace on the drive and rely on the local version of Eclipse, but that isn't an option most of the time.

The setup I have works great, until I use it on a computer that assigns my USB drive a different drive letter. Then I have to re-configure my workspace directory settings and set up a new interpreter every time the drive letter changes.

Is there any way to just have Eclipse look down from the root of the drive instead of relying on system drive letters to find the interpreter / workspace?